# Sort links don't retain page anchor in django-tables2

Tags: python, sorting, anchor, django-tables2

I have a page with Bootstrap-style tabs that uses anchors.  When I click a header field to sort one of the tables, the sorting works fine, but the result URL doesn't retain the original `#anchor` location and I am sent to a different tab.

[image]

Original URL: http://localhost:8000/wakemeup/myaccount#reputation
Actual Sort URL: http://localhost:8000/wakemeup/myaccount?sort=pointvalue

Desired Sort URL: http://localhost:8000/wakemeup/myaccount#reputation?sort=pointvalue

### Problem

How can I get the table sort headers to retain the original anchor location in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the anchors to the `href` attributes of the sorting link tags. You can achieve this by a few lines of JavaScript (assuming you already use jQuery because of bootstrap):

```
var tab_id = '#table';
$(tab_id).find('a').each(function(el) {
    $(el).attr('href', $(el).attr('href') + tab_id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give this a try.